A simple question about bounding a sum
Let $\Lambda_N:=\{-N+1,\dots,N-1\}^2\subset\mathbb{Z}^2$ be a set of lattice points in $\mathbb{Z}^2,$ and let $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}.$ For $x\in\Lambda_N$ with $\|x\|_2>\gamma^{-1}$(with $\|\cdot\|$ being the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$), consider the following sum:
$$\sum_{x\in\Lambda_N\\\|x\|_2>\gamma^{-1}}\frac{\gamma^2}{\|\gamma x\|_2^6}+\frac{\gamma^2}{\|\gamma x\|_2^4}+\frac{\gamma^2}{\|\gamma x\|_2^2}\quad (*).$$
The paper that I'm reading states that the sum $(*)$ could be bounded by: $C\log(\gamma^{-1}),$ where $C$ is a constant. But I didn't see where this $\log(\gamma^{-1})$ comes from?

My thoughts:
With $\|x\|>\gamma^{-1},$ we have $\frac{1}{\|\gamma x\|_2}< 1.$ So the sum $(*)$ could be bounded by
$$(*)\leq \sum_{x\in\Lambda_N\\\|x\|_2\geq\gamma^{-1}}\gamma^2\leq\gamma^2\times \#\big\{x\in\Lambda_N:\|x\|_2>\gamma\big\}.$$
But the number of point in the set $\big\{x\in\Lambda_N:\|x\|_2>\gamma\big\}$ is (roughly) bounded by $(N-1)^2-C\gamma^{-2},$ this gives us
$$(*)\leq \gamma^2\big((N-1)^2-C\gamma^{-2}\big)=\frac{(N-1)^2}{N}-C, (\text{because $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$})$$
which is much worse than the bound $\log(\gamma^{-1})=\log\sqrt{N}.$

Is there any way I could improve my method, to get $(*)\leq C\log(\gamma^{-1})?$
Thank you very much for any ideas and helps:-)

First, the condition $\|x\|_2>\gamma^{-1}$ leads to $\frac{1}{\|\gamma x\|_2} <1$, which implies that $\frac{\gamma^2}{\|\gamma x\|_2^2}$ dominates the other terms in the sum. Hence, we only have to bound the following sum:
$$\sum_{x\in\Lambda_N\\\|x\|_2>\gamma^{-1}} \frac{\gamma^2}{\|\gamma x\|_2^2} = \sum_{x\in\Lambda_N\\\|x\|_2>\gamma^{-1}} \frac{1}{\| x\|_2^2} \le \sum_{\| x \|  \le 2N} \frac{1}{\| x\|_2^2} . $$
To prove this sum scales like $\log(N) = 2 \log(\sqrt N)$ you can use an argument similar to the one used for proving the harmonic series scales like $\log N$: approximate the sum with an integral
$$\sum_{\| x \|  \le 2N} \frac{1}{\| x\|_2^2} \sim \int\int_{\| x \|  \le 2N} \frac{1}{\| x\|_2^2} dx $$
Using the polar substitution you get
$$\int\int_{\| x \|  \le 2N} \frac{1}{\| x\|_2^2} dx = 2 \pi \int_0^{2N} \frac 1 {r^2} r dr \sim \log N,$$
which is the desired estimate.

Hey, thank you so much for your answer, which helps a lot! But I think the integrand is not integrable around the origin, how do you know that you could approximate the sum using this integral?
